# Complete Noetherian local ring with residue field $\mathbb{F}_p$ is an algebra over the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, noetherian, local-rings

Let $R$ be a complete, Noetherian, local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and residue field $R/\mathfrak{m} \cong \mathbb{F}_p$. Note that by "complete", we mean that
$$
R \cong \varprojlim_n R/\mathfrak{m}^n.
$$

I am trying to show that $R$ is an algebra over the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

**My attempt**

Since we want to construct a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p \to R$, I would like to construct compatible homomorphisms
$$
R \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}.
$$
which would give a cone on the inverse system used to define
$$
\mathbb{Z}_p = \varprojlim_n \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z},
$$
and hence induce a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p \to R$ be the universal property of limits. For $n=1$, there is an obvious candidate, namely the quotient map $\varphi_1:R \to R/\mathfrak{m} \cong \mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Now we would like a homomorphism $\varphi_2:R \to \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ such that the composition
$$
R \overset{\varphi_2}{\to} \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}
$$
is the same as $\varphi_1$. Now, I would like it to be the case that $R/\mathfrak{m}^n =\cong \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, which would allows us to define all higher maps the same way we definded $\varphi_1$. However, I don't see why this would be the case, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't a system of compatible maps $R \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ induce a map $R \to \mathbb{Z}_p$, not a map $\mathbb{Z}_p \to R$?

Comment: @DanielHast you got me there - thanks

Comment: I guess if one takes Witt vector machinery for granted, one would easily get a map $W(\mathbb F_p) \rightarrow R$ here, and $W(\mathbb F_p) \cong \mathbb Z_p$, but that might be considered overkill. Then again, it would be interesting to compare the hands-on but "tiresome" approach in Lubin's answer to how that Witt functoriality is proven.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg in fact I was given this problem as a way to understand why coefficient rings are $W(k)$-algebras for any finite field $k$. I was told that the full proof is similar to this special case; do you disagree?

Comment: I believe it is similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @DanielHast hints in his comment, you’re looking for a nonexistent thing. There’s no ring homomorphism from $R=\Bbb Z_p[\sqrt p\,]$ to $\Bbb Z_p$, for instance, even though this $R$ definitely is the kind of complete ring you’re considering. The maximal ideal of $R$ is $\mathfrak m=\langle\sqrt p, p\rangle$, where the angle brackets denote an enumeration of the $\Bbb Z_p$-basis. And it is not true that $R/\mathfrak m^2\cong \Bbb Z_p/(p)^2$.

What you want is a map $\Bbb Z_p\to R\,$; that’s what makes $R$ a $\Bbb Z_p$-algebra. You can construct it by taking the necessary map $\Bbb Z\to R$, and then showing that $p$-adically convergent sequences of elements of $\Bbb Z$ get carried to $\mathfrak m$-adically convergent sequences of elements of $R$. As I recall, it may be rather tiresome to verify that you’ve defined a good ring morphism $\Bbb Z_p\to R$.

Comment: Excellent point - how foolish of me! Thank you for pointing out my mistake.